# Is it possible to get the value of steps_per_epoch with which fit was executed?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

Is it possible to get the value of `steps_per_epoch` with which `fit` was executed?

Please, do not suggest me to divide the number of training examples by the batch size. I am wondering if this can be retrieved from a property of the model or something.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all the models in Keras have a default [`History`](http://keras.io/callbacks/#history) callback which basically holds the history of training of the model. One piece of information which is stored in this callback is the value of `steps_per_epoch` which could be accessed using `model.history.params['steps']`.

Note that if the model has been saved after training, and then is loaded back later, then it may not be possible to access its History callback; that's because, as far as I know, the callback(s) is not persisted when saving the model.